# Is it possible to add DataFrame`s data to existing csv file?

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, sftp

In remote **SFTP** server I have `csv` file with some data. Is it possible to add DataFrame's data to this existing file? In other words, previous data inside csv file should not be overwritten.

I use [spark-sftp](https://github.com/springml/spark-sftp) library to this task and notice that the code below recreate the file. In other words, previous data inside csv file disappears. What you can advise to improve this situation?

```
val df: DataFrame = Seq(
    ("Alex", "2018-01-01 00:00:00", "2018-02-01 00:00:00", "OUT"),
    ("Bob", "2018-02-01 00:00:00", "2018-02-05 00:00:00", "IN"),
    ("Kate", "2018-02-01 00:00:00", "2018-02-05 00:00:00", "IN"),
    ("Alice", "2018-02-01 00:00:00", "2018-02-05 00:00:00", "OUT"),
).toDF("FIRST_NAME", "START_DATE", "END_DATE", "STATUS")

df.write.
    format("com.springml.spark.sftp").
    option("host", "XXXX").
    option("username", "XXXX").
    option("password", "****").
    option("fileType", "csv").
    option("delimiter", ";").
    save("/PATH/test.csv")
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add the append mode option:

```
    mode(SaveMode.Append).
```

Full example:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode
df.write.
    format("com.springml.spark.sftp").
    option("host", "XXXX").
    option("username", "XXXX").
    option("password", "****").
    option("fileType", "csv").
    option("delimiter", ";").
    mode(SaveMode.Append).
    save("/PATH/test.csv")
```

Comment: Hello! I tried your code but unfortunately it overwrites the existing csv file. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: u sure? Can you please post your whole code just to check it? Is it exactly the same as mine?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. I just add `mode(SaveMode.Append)` as you recommended, that's all. Do you test your code? It seems to me that `spark-sftp` library in [this](https://github.com/springml/spark-sftp/blob/090917547001574afa93cddaf2a022151a3f4260/src/main/scala/com/springml/spark/sftp/DefaultSource.scala#L249) place ignore our `mode` option. What do you think about that assumption?

Answer (score 0):

You need to write in append mode.

```
df.write.
mode("append").
format("com.springml.spark.sftp")
...
```

Comment: Hello! I tried your code but unfortunately it overwrites the existing csv file. Do you have any other ideas?